# What could a leaked UIImage of size 16 Bytes indicate?

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uiimage, calayer, instruments

16 Bytes is pretty small, right? None of the UIImages I create in my app are that small, yet the Leaks Instrument is reporting a leaked UIimage of size 16 Bytes... Any clues on what this could be? Incidentally, there was also a leaked CALayer object of 48 bytes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImage`s are just a thin wrapper around `CGImageRef`s; most likely you have an uninitialized `UIImage` somewhere (or something similar):

```
- (void)leakImage
{
    UIImage *leaked = [UIImage alloc];
}
```